# Issue with deleting google account

Tags: google-workspace

It seems impossible to delete my google account. I cannot get to step 4 I have never had a google cloud resource. (the delete button is not active)
I tried everything.

[image]

Below is a snap form the google cloud console
The delete button is not active and not only that even before somehow creating the project  I had the same problem with step 4 from previous picture.

[image]

Thank you in advance!